# How to handle post data in yii2 restful service?

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, yii2

I'm sending an array with $htpp post like though :

```
var results = services.transaction('orderdetails/insert',
                       {customer_id: $scope.order.customer_id, data: $scope.orderDetail});
```

where $scope.orderdetail is an array of data retrieved from ui_grid :

```
            $scope.orderDetail = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < gridLength; i++) {
                $scope.orderDetail.push({
                "product_id": $scope.grid[i].product.id,
                "quantity": $scope.grid[i].quantity,
                "custom_price": $scope.grid[i].price
            });

        }
```

and handling it in my actionInsert():

```
public function actionInsert() {
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $customer_id = $request->getBodyParam('customer_id');
    $data = $request->getBodyParam('data');
}
```

the problem is that the array $data has no keys when I try to iterate through
it in my actionInsert. however when I return it I get this data as response, tellin that its an array:

```
data:Array[2]
0: Object
custom_price: 5000
product_id: 4
quantity: 6
1: Object
custom_price: 8000
product_id: 2
quantity: 8
```

My goal is to insert those data using transaction, following these steps:

1- insert the customer_id in table order

2-get last order id to insert it in orderdetails

3- insert the array of other value, but I want order id to be added in each insert.

I have made it like this:

```
    $sql1 = "insert into `order`(customer_id) values($customer_id);";
    $sql2 = 'select @orderNumber := max(id) from `order`;';

//**Transaction**//
    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $connection->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
        $connection->createCommand($sql2)->execute();

            $connection->createCommand("INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (oder_id, product_id, quantity, custom_price) "
                    . "VALUES (@orderNumber, $values")->execute();


        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) { // an exception is raised if a query fails
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
    //**end transaction
```

I know I have to use something like this:

```
foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {

        $fields[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'" . \Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($data[$key]) . "'";

}
$fields = implode(",", $fields);
$values = implode(",", $values);
```

but as I mentioned before that my $data has unexpected keys 0, 1, and so on, but I need the custom_price and others. why the array isn't as expected and how to make the insert statement with @orderNumber appended to first element in each array object.

Thank you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
$sql1 = "insert into `order`(customer_id) values($customer_id);";
    //**Transaction**//
    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $connection->createCommand($sql1)->execute();

        $orderNumber = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $model = new Orderdetails;
            $model->order_id = $orderNumber;
            $model->attributes = $value;
            if (!$model->save()) {
                throw new Exception('Insertion failed');
            }
        }
        //.... other SQL executions
        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) { // an exception is raised if a query fails
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
    //**end transaction
```